# loop within loop vba

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have the following issue i can't get my head around.

I have the following list of data:

```
Row           Value 

DK12_DK13       2   
DK12            4
DK15            3
DK11            3
DK13            5
```

What i want my function to do, is to loop through the rows column, to select the first 4 (and last 4) characters and save them in a string. Next i then want to store the value of column b (values) that correponds to to the 4 first characters in a new string.

To Clarify, the first string would be DK12 i would then use this string to look for the 4 character DK12 in column A which has the value 4, and then have the value 4 stored in another string. I quess this wuld require me to have a loop within a loop. Right now i have the following code, but i am kinda stuck here, when i want to loop over the data i have stored in the strings from the first loop. Hope my explanation makes sense:

```
Sub Test()
Dim I As Integer
Dim L_text As String
Dim R_text As String
Dim Full_text As String
Dim L_Value As String

For I = 5 To 9

L_text = Left(Range("A" & I), 4)
R_text = Right(Range("A" & I), 4)

 If Len(Range("A" & I)) = 9 Then

 L_text = Left(Range("A" & I), 4)
 R_text = Right(Range("A" & I), 4)
 Full_text = Left(Range("A" & I), 9)

     End If
   Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Wouldn't you just reference the worksheet table where the data is stored?  Why not store the lookup and value in an array instead of using strings?  There's so much here that doesn't make sense.

Comment: `VLOOKUP` (which can be used from VBA) is the natural way to retrieve values in a spreadsheet which correspond to keys in an adjacent column. Alternatively, if the data is large enough, it would pay to load it into a dictionary. It really isn't clear what you are trying to do. Column A contains two types of strings, some with 4 characters and some with 9, and you are using strings extracted from the 9 character strings to serve as keys (which are the 4-character strings)? Seems odd, but if so -- what are you planning to do with the retrieved values? Please clarify.

Comment: Hi, What i am trying to do, is to make a function that will add all values to based on the string with 9 characters. So that it would be DK12_DK13 + DK12 + DK13, and then have the 4 character strings deleted.

But out of pure curiosity, is it posible to have to extend my funtion with an extra loop?